# Not able to run the Reporting like HTML,JSON and XML In cucumber

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, serenity-bdd, cucumber-junit

I am using Cucumber with Junit, I can able to run the feature file and able to get the result in consol. I am not able to run the report. while running the html,json,xml report it show like initialization error. Please help me how to resolve the error .

Comment: No info to help. Please share pom file, what command or how did you try to run the report?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.